# Verifying intersection of two lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to check whether the interaction provided is the correct intersection of two lists. Example query list:

```
?- intersectionL([1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,6],[1,3]).
/* expected output: true. */

?- intersectionL([1,2,3,4],[1,3,5,6],X).
/* expected output: X = [1,3]. */

?- intersectionL([1,2,3],[4,3],[3]).
/* expected output: true. */
```

I have written a function to calculate the intersection of two lists (intersectionL). From there I want to verify whether the third argument given is the same as the intersection I found (intersectionHelper).

```
intersectHelper([], []).
intersectHelper([H1|T1], [H2|T2]):-
    H1 = H2, intersectHelper(T1, T2).

intersectionL([], X, []). 
intersectionL([H1|T1], L2, [H1|Res]):- 
  member(H1, L2), intersectionL(T1, L2, Res). 
  intersectionL([X|T1], L2, Res):- 
    intersectionL(T1, L2, Res).
```

I am having two problems: Firstly, how do I use intersectionHelper within intersectionL. Secondly, how do I output the list of intersections if no list is provided (like in query 2 above).

Edit: I was able to solve it for anyone else interested. I do not require intersectionHelper.

```
intersectionL([], X, []). 
intersectionL([H1|T1], L2, [H1|Res]):- 
  member(H1, L2), intersectionL(T1, L2, Res). 
  intersectionL([X|T1], L2, Res):- 
    intersectionL(T1, L2, Res).
```

Comment: Why do you need `intersectionHelper/2` here in the first place?

Comment: I thought it was the correct approach for queries like 1 and 3 above. How else do I do it?

Answer (score -2):

Not an answer but there I note that there is a RED CUT missing in `intersectionL/3`:

For example, computing the intersection of `[1,2,3]` and `[1,4,5]` gives two solutions, only one of which is desired:

```
?- intersectionL([1,2,3],[1,4,5],L).
L = [1] ;  % desired
L = [].    % not desired
```

We need to add a guard condition in the second clause:

```
intersectionL([], X, []). 

intersectionL([H1|T1], L2, [H1|Res]):- 
  member(H1, L2), intersectionL(T1, L2, Res). 

intersectionL([X|T1], L2, Res):- 
  \+member(H1, L2), intersectionL(T1, L2, Res).
```

or use a "red cut" to tell Prolog to not try the third clause if the second succeeded (this is ugly):

```
intersectionL([], X, []). 

intersectionL([H1|T1], L2, [H1|Res]):- 
  member(H1, L2),!,intersectionL(T1, L2, Res). 

intersectionL([X|T1], L2, Res):- 
  intersectionL(T1, L2, Res).
```

Best is to have an explicit guard with a green cut to shed any choicepoints that are of no use, while still staying declarative:

```
intersectionL([], _, []). 

intersectionL([H1|T1], L2, [H1|Res]):- 
  member(H1, L2),!,intersectionL(T1, L2, Res). 

intersectionL([H1|T1], L2, Res):- 
  \+member(H1, L2),!,intersectionL(T1, L2, Res).
```

Now it works, one solution only.

```
?- intersectionL([1,2,3],[1,4,5],L).
L = [1].
```